# Case sql not working

Tags: sql, group-by, case, exists

I have a select statement I am trying to make for a report. I have it pulling data and everything I need but I noticed that since I have to use the group by it is dropping off rows that do not exist in a table. How can I stop this or make it work.

```
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN direction = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) InBound, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN direction = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OutBound, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN direction = 'I' THEN p.duration ELSE 0 END) InBoundTime, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN direction = 'O' THEN p.duration ELSE 0 END) OutBoundTime, 
       u.fullname, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN EXISTS (SELECT g.goalamount 
                        FROM   [tblbrokergoals] AS g 
                        WHERE  ( g.goaldate BETWEEN 
                                 '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-27' )) 
         THEN 
           g.goalamount 
           ELSE 0 
         END )  AS GoalAmount 
FROM   [tblphonelogs] AS p 
       LEFT JOIN [tblusers] AS u 
              ON u.fullname = p.phonename 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [tblbrokergoals] AS g 
                    ON u.fullname = g.brokername 
WHERE  ( calldatetime BETWEEN '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-27' ) 
       AND ( u.userid IS NOT NULL ) 
       AND ( u.direxclude <> '11' ) 
       AND u.termdate IS NULL 
       AND ( g.goaldate BETWEEN '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-27' ) 
GROUP  BY u.fullname, 
          g.goalamount;
```

This works and grabs all the data when the user is in BrokerGoals but, when the user is not in broker goals it just deletes that row on the returned result set. How can I get it so when the user doesnt not exist in the brokergoals table to set that value as 0 or -- so the row does not get deleted.

Comment: The problem is you need one aditional `LEFT JOIN`. I just answer almost the exact same question minutes ago. let me know if that help http://stackoverflow.com/a/36317252/3470178

Comment: I dont have permissions to create a new table in the database. Sometime the users are in the brokers goals sometimes they are not depends on if they are in the office or not but if they do not have a value in the brokers goals it still should show 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.FullName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InBound,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OutBound,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'I' THEN p.Duration ELSE 0 END) InBoundTime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Direction = 'O' THEN p.Duration ELSE 0 END) OutBoundTime,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT g.GoalAmount
        FROM [Portal].[dbo].[tblBrokerGoals] AS g
        WHERE g.GoalDate BETWEEN '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-27'
            AND u.FullName = g.BrokerName
    ) THEN (
        SELECT g.GoalAmount
        FROM [Portal].[dbo].[tblBrokerGoals] AS g
        WHERE g.GoalDate BETWEEN '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-27'
            AND u.FullName = g.BrokerName
    ) ELSE '0' END AS GoalAmount
FROM [Portal].[dbo].[tblUsers] AS u
LEFT JOIN [Portal].[dbo].[tblPhoneLogs] AS p
    ON u.FullName = p.PhoneName
WHERE u.UserID IS NOT NULL
    AND u.DirExclude <> '11'
    AND u.TermDate IS NULL
    AND p.CallDateTime BETWEEN '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-27'
GROUP BY u.FullName
```

This is what I ended up doing to fix my problem. I added the Case When Exists statement and in the then statement did the select else it is 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `brokers` table then you can use it for your `left join`

```
SELECT b.broker_id, ....
FROM brokers b
LEFT JOIN .... ALL YOUR OTHER TABLES
....
GROUP BY b.broker_id, ....
```

If your brokers has duplicate names then use

```
SELECT b.broker_id, ....
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT broker_id
      FROM brokers) b
LEFT JOIN .... ALL YOUR OTHER TABLES
....
GROUP BY b.broker_id,   ....
```

Comment: Thats what I changed it too and it still is getting rid of the rows where the broker does not exist in the brokergoals table because of the group by

Comment: I ended up fixing it in the select case statement i had to make the then the select statement also and the else is 0 for it to work.

Comment: Then the error is somewhere else. As I say the other question, remove the agregations on the select and just use the same values as the `GROUP BY` you will see the rows arent there

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing ( CASE 
           WHEN EXISTS (SELECT g.goalamount 
                        FROM   [tblbrokergoals] AS g 
                        WHERE  ( g.goaldate BETWEEN 
                                 '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-27' )) 
         THEN 
           g.goalamount 
           ELSE 0 
         END )  AS GoalAmount
to just g.goalamount, as you already have that date condition in where clause